# Adding/removing session variables on Page OnInit/OnLoad in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I am using C#.

I am having below code in C#:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Session["boolSignOn"].ToString() == "true".ToString())              
        {              
            lblPanelOpen.Text = Session["panelOpen"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lblPanelOpen.Text = Session["panelOpen"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Error processing request:" + ex.Message);
    }
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["panelOpen"].ToString()))
        {
            lblPanelOpen.Text = string.Empty;
            Session.Remove("panelOpen");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Unable to remove the session variable:" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In above code I am having a `Session["panelOpen"]` variable which is created from another user control and once my page is trying to render, I am storing `Session["panelOpen"]` in my hidden `lblPanelOpen.Text` on page `OnInit()` method, however when page is loaded completely then I am trying to remove the session variable.

Please suggest!

Comment: You could use PageLoadComplete event for that.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is that, on my home page there are slider panels which get opens when user click one of them, and if panel is open and user clicks on login link for to get login, after the login functionality is done the user is redirected back to its same page, here I am trying to open the same panel which was clicked by user before going for login. Above in onit was working fine, but only issue is that it until that session variable is there it will open same panel if user comes back to home page. Please suggest

Comment: @MKS can you please exp[lain what u mean by "but only issue is that it until that session variable is there it will open same panel if user comes back to home page". Are you saying that even if user is not logged in the same panel opens for every user... please explain!!

Comment: No, Look Session["panelOpen"] variable will contain the ID of the panel which is clicked by user, say example I have 5 panel on my homepage and user clicks on 2 panel and opens it and in between he clicks the login link to get login in application, then he is redirected to login page with the values of panel open in our case it is 2, now on login page i am setting the Session["panelOpen"] with value 2 and then from login page user is redirected back to homepage, now here I am checking for session vairable and according to that I am opening the same panel which he has clicked before login.

Comment: @MKS really it still unclear to me, I understand what you are trying to do, you have a panel on your home page and when the user request to login when he redirected to the home page after the login process you want to keep the state of the panel as it was before the login. But it is unclear to me how you are doing this now and what is your problem?

Comment: @MKS, The question here does the session of the anonymous user still the same for the user when he login? I don't have an answer for this question maybe I should post it :), though I think it is not the same and thus you can't use the session to accomplish your request. Are you getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object ?

Comment: With continuation of the above comments - I am getting the panel open without any problem, however the problem is that if user clicks another page from the homepage and comes back to homepage the same panel gets open as according to code it still check the Session["panelOpen"] value in our case it is 2 so second panel will again open. I just want to open the once after that it will behave as normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK i think i get it. In your first method that is OnInit you are only checking for `boolSignOn` to be null or empty but not for the `panelOpen`.

try this intead:

```
 if (Session["boolSignOn"].ToString() == "true".ToString() && Session["panelOpen"] != null)
```

Also change your else part.
and change your whole code to:

**Update here is the full code i tried**

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Change your condition here
        if (Session["boolSignOn"].ToString() == "true".ToString() && Session["panelOpen"] != null)               
        {              
            lblPanelOpen.Text = Session["panelOpen"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            //Dont set text to panelOpen here
            lblPanelOpen.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Error processing request:" + ex.Message);
    }
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["panelOpen"].ToString()))
        {
            // No need to set it here it will be set in next load in OnInit call 
            //lblPanelOpen.Text = string.Empty;
            Session.Remove("panelOpen");
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Logger.Error("Unable to remove the session variable:" + ex.Message);
   }
```

}

I hope this may work. Give it a try

Comment: I think you need to look and understand my complete flow, please see my comments, above code never can work as Session["panelOpen"] will never be null

Comment: @MKS Explain why it will not be null. in your OnLoad Method you are removing the session variable so if you try to access again it will be null. And FYI i have tried this code and its working.

Comment: I can't have && condition as I am also maintaining some html on basis of if (Session["boolSignOn"].ToString() == "true".ToString() && Session["panelOpen"] != null), after putting your && condition it works first time but when I do ctrl+F5 for the page it doesn't come inside the loop, inside loop I am checking the Session["boolSignOn"] conditionally, please suggest without and condition, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @MKS it seems that you have a lot of other code as well.. can you show that please. It will be helpful in answering your scenario. If you have problem with && statement then have a nested if for panelOpen and only surround the (`lblPanelOpen.Text = Session["panelOpen"].ToString();
`) part in it.

Comment: Thanks @Shekhar, I will check your code and will update my comments tomorrow..thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Ok here we go,

When the user press the login link or button you store a value in a session variable in your case

```
Session["boolSignOn"] = true;
Session["panelOpen"] = blah blah; // your thing to keep;
```

The user login and the page redirected to the home page in the page load you check the Session["boolSignOn"] if it has value and it is true then you apply the panel changes you need.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["boolSignOn"] != null && (bool)Session["boolSignOn"] == true)
    {
       // get the Session["panelOpen"] and do the changes you need.
    }
}
```

In your home page Page_Unload if the Session["boolSignOn"] has value and it is true you clear both Session["boolSignOn"] and Session["openPanel"],

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["boolSignOn"] != null && (bool)Session["boolSignOn"] == true)
    {
        Session["boolSignOn"] = null;
        Session["openPanel"] = null;
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Many Thanks @A_Nablsi, my homepage.aspx does not have .cs code file its only using master page and unfortunaltly master page also not having the codebehind. I have got two usercontrols on home page and tried with them its not working it is removing the session values before and the panel remain close. Please see my above code for the usercontrol, I have already checked with protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)

Comment: You should use `Session["boolSignOn"] as bool? ?? false`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I am not able to understand your problem correctly however I can see a blue print of your issue and here are few steps that you may want to follow to see if this fixes your issue.

1) When the user opens a panel (assuming there should be a click event when the user clicks to open the panel). So add code in the click event to create and save a session variable with the Panel ID that is open.

2) Assuming that the user has completed the login process when you redirect the user back to the same page you should be able to access the session variable and also remove it in OnLoad event.

3) If this does not work try using Server.Transfer to redirect the user back to the same page.

4) Also did you tried doing Session.Clear(); does this work?

Comment: I am usint http-->https-->http concept as there is secure login authentication is there, so I think server.transfer will not work for me as they will be treated as different domain. Why you said to try session.clear() any ideas?

Comment: yeah it might look a bit funny however I was assuming that you were trying to remove a session variable... I just wanted to test and see if it is at least clearing all the session data at the point you are trying to remove the session variable, that way we can at least see if its clearing all the session data that was stored (I know that it will clear all other session info) but it just a trial and error thing to see why its behaving like that... (also make sure you are doing Session.Clear() in the last line of your OnLoad code)